# R Passing Name of List Objects to List Objects Themselves

Tags: r, list, lapply, names

I receive a named list of data frames using an R API to a data vendor. Below is how I would struct a similar structure.

```
spec1 <- data.frame(speed = 100, wt = 5, price = 10)
spec2 <- data.frame(speed = 1000, wt = 1, price = 100)
spec3 <- data.frame(speed = 1, wt = 50, price = 5)
mylist <- list(car = spec1,exotic = spec2, truck = spec3)
```

My goal is to turn this into a flat data frame like below so that I can export it into an SQL database.

```
car_type   speed     wt     price
--------   ------    ----   -----
car        100       5      10        
exotic     1000      1      100 
truck      1         50     5
```

My problem is that the identifier for "car_type" is stored as the name of the data frame in the list, and I don't know how to pass it to a repeat function to populate the table.

For example I use the following to get the car_type from the names of the items in the list

```
car_type <- sapply(seq_along(mylist), function(x) names(mylist)[x])
```

And then I use the following to repeat the a car_type (substituted by "X") in the underlying tables and then append.

```
category <- lapply(mylist, function(y) rep("X" ,dim(y)[1]))
mylist <- lapply(seq_along(mylist), function(x)
```

However, I can't seem to manage to pass the names found in car_type back into create a new category column in my dataset, which will persist when it's flattened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or a `base R` option would be with `Map` to create the 'car_type' from the `names` of 'mylist' and then `rbind` the `list` elements

```
do.call(rbind, unname(Map(cbind, car_type = names(mylist), mylist)))
#   car_type speed wt price
#1      car   100  5    10
#2   exotic  1000  1   100
#3    truck     1 50     5
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use either one of those two:

```
  dplyr::bind_rows(mylist, .id = "car_type")
  data.table::rbindlist(mylist, idcol = "car_type")
```

both output:

```
      car_type speed wt price
1:      car   100  5    10
2:   exotic  1000  1   100
3:    truck     1 50     5
```

Comment: LOL. Brilliant and so easy. Spent so many hours trying to figure this out. Thanks so much @ friep

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more readable:

```
library(magrittr)
mylist %>% do.call(rbind,.) %>% transform(car_type = rownames(.)) %>% set_rownames(NULL)
```